# How to get the ERD to show more information?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I want to discuss about my db and the ERD I have, shows only the table column names, their types and the relationships between tables (in the static view).

Is it possible to alter some setting and make it add more information(default value, foreign key relationships) to the ERD (The exported static view should show these)?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. The shown values are hard coded.